# C# equivalent of Java Class.this

Tags: java, c#, this

**Question :** What can be the *C#* equivalent of *Java* `Class.this` ?

**Why :** Suppose I've same class *Form1* in both *Java* and *C#*. In *Java* we can write `Form1.this`, how this can be written in *C#*.

Comment: To the downvoter: this is a very reasonable question.  (potentially it's a dup?)  But for someone coming from Java, the fact that C# does not have anything like Java-style inner classes (as opposed to C# nested classes / Java static inner classes) is one that will often be surprising to a new Java developer learning about C#.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no equivalent, C# has no nested class support where it also tracks outer instances. If needed you pass a pointer yourself and store it in a field/property.

If all you want is the normal `this` to reference members in the same instance, simply use the `this` keyword. Or even better, don't -- it's implied.

Comment: I got it. Thank you @Blindy for the quick response.